Extract e-mail addresses from msg files -Python
I am trying to write a script that will extract e-mail address from Outlook .msg files. However, some .msg files could have another .msg files attached in it.
def extract_emails_from_folder(folder_path, excluded_email):
# Create an empty set to store extracted email addresses
email_addresses = set()

# Iterate through each file in the folder
for filename in os.listdir(folder_path):
    # Check if the file is an MSG file
    if filename.endswith('.msg'):
        file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)
        # Extract email addresses from the MSG file
        email_addresses.update(extract_emails_from_msg(file_path, excluded_email))

# Create a DataFrame to store the email addresses
df = pd.DataFrame({'Email Addresses': list(email_addresses)})
print(df)

Some of the e-mail addresses in the the .msg files are attached in another .msg files. May I know how can I also extract those e-mail addresses as well?

Your indentation is clearly wrong, but what's less clear is how it ought to be indented. Don't make us guess; please [edit] to fix it. On the desktop version of this site, you can get code marked up for you by pasting your code, selecting the pasted block, and typing ctrl-K. Going forward, probably notice that you get a preview of what your post will look like below the editing pane. If your screen is wide enough, you also get a help button at the right of the editor's menu strip, with a link to the full editing help

how to ask a good question:
how to ask

also include the import os and import pandas as pd in the minimal reproducible example

You can use the 'extract_msg' library

pip install extract-msg

from extract_msg import Message

def extract_emails_from_folder(folder_path, excluded_email):
    try:
        msg = Message(folder_path)
        if(msg.sender_email not in exlcude_email) and (msg.receiver_email not in exlcude_email) and (msg.cc not in exlcude_email):
            return [msg.sender_email, msg.receiver_email, msg.cc]
        else:
            return []
    except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error extracting email addresses from {folder_path}: {e}")
            return []

excluded_email = ["Your Excluded Mails here"]
email_addresses = set()
# Iterate through each file in the folder
for filename in os.listdir(folder_path):
    # Check if the file is an MSG file
    if filename.endswith('.msg'):
        file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)
        # Extract email addresses from the MSG file
        extracted_mail = extract_emails_from_msg(file_path, excluded_email)
        if(extracted_mail==[]):
            pass
        email_addresses.update(extracted_mail)

# Create a DataFrame to store the email addresses
df = pd.DataFrame({'Email Addresses': list(email_addresses)})
print(df)

